# F-connect all of sudden not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As of the other day everything was working with Facebook Connect.  Now I have to click "Connect" twice for it log me in.

Comment: seems something has happened recently.  http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect/issues#issue/23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm and vote on this bug:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11733

Comment: Just did it...Thanks for the link